# Regex that matches 15th October 09:00 to 23rd October 11:00?

Tags: regex

I need a Regex that matches (15th October 09:00 to 23rd October 11:00) using the following data format:

```
Wed Oct 22 18:26:09 BST 2014 => Match
Wed Oct 21 09:26:09 BST 2014 => Match
Wed Oct 14 11:00:09 BST 2014
Wed Oct 01 23:26:09 BST 2014
Wed Oct 28 18:26:09 BST 2014
Wed Oct 23 08:26:09 BST 2014 => Match
Wed Oct 13 18:26:09 BST 2014
Wed Oct 01 18:26:09 BST 2014
```

Can anybody help? I am using PigLatin on Hadoop but it uses the Java Regex system.

Comment: This is not a job for regular expressions.

Comment: Better add your programming language as a new tag in your post.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regexp for this? How would a non-regexp solution fail to meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with numeric ranges isn't handy in a regex pattern, however it can be done in a effecient way if you take care of the path the regex engine will follow. For example, in the following patterns, when the regex engine succeed in a branch, you can be sure that it can't succeed in an other branch (it's how the pattern is build). So even if the pattern seems long, it provides to the regex engine the shorter way to succeed or to fail:

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kM5nI1/1)

compact version:

```
Oct (?>1(?:[6-9] [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|5 (?:[12][0-9]|09):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})|2(?:[0-2] [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|3 (?:(?:0[0-9]|10):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}|11:00:00))) BST 2014
```

readable version:

```
Oct\ 
(?>
    1
    (?:
        [6-9] \ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
      |
        5 \ (?: [12][0-9] | 09 ) : [0-9]{2} : [0-9]{2}
    )
  |
    2
    (?:
        [0-2] \ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
      |
        3 \ 
        (?:
            (?:0[0-9]|10):[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
          |
            11:00:00
        )
    )
)
\ BST\ 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it probably would be better to convert the string to date and then use value comparison but if you really want to do it this way:

```
Oct\s(1[6-9] |2[012] |15 (09|[12])|23 (0|10|11:00:00))[:\d]+
```

Here's the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/zB9cB1/1)

If you want the matching to stop at Oct 25 11:00:00 instead of 23:

```
Oct\s(1[6-9] |2[0-4] |15 (09|[12])|25 (0|10|11:00:00))[:\d]+
```

[enter link description here](http://regex101.com/r/zB9cB1/2)

Comment: These dont work as i need it to stop matching after 11.00 on the 25th october and start matching on the 9th october from 11.00. I know this is a horrible method but I literally have 12 hours to fix this.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Sean already pointed out, this isn't really what Regexes are good for, but assuming you still want to do below is a regex that should work for you.

```
^\w+\sOct\s(?:(15)|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|(23))\s(?(1)(?:09|[12]\d):.+|(?(2)(?:(?:11|10)|0\d):.+|.+))$
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zP1sK4/3)

You didn't specify the language you're using or the Regex engine, so I tried to make it generic.

Just to hit the high points on why this works, I'm assuming you understand the basics of using Regexes.

```
^                                   -- Beginning character anchor
\w+\sOct\s                          -- This grabs the 'Wed Oct ' piece
(?:(15)|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|(23))  -- This is the list of days supported (notice I capture the 15th and 23rd. Very important for the next part
\s
(?(1)                               -- this is a conditional statement, if group 1 matched, then do this else do this
 (?:09|[12]\d):.+                   -- so if it's the 15th, check to see if the time is greater than or equal to 9am
 |                                  -- ELSE
 (?(2)                              -- if it's the 23, check to see if it's before 11am
   (?:(?:11|10)|0\d):.+
 |
 .+)                                --otherwise, we don't care what time it is
)$
```

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: Thanks for pointing that out. I had missed the time piece completely. I updated my answer to support the time.